# Python cannot allocate even 200MB of memory while calling a R function using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to implement R's mRMRe from Python for feature selection but even for a simple command like :

```
dd = pymrmr.mRMR_data(data)
```

It says cannot allocate vector. Below is the error:

[image]

Should I clear R's memory from within Python to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of the same type of error by increasing the memory limit

```
from rpy2 import robjects
R = robjects.r


R('memory.limit()')
R('memory.limit(size = 10000)') ## in MB
R('memory.limit()')

…
R('gc()')## trigger garbage collection
```